# Fix HTML/CSS Animations performance

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have made a HTML page with css animation and transitions

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="team">
<div class="row first">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="row second">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.0.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.0.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.0.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.0.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable right-side">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.6.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.6.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.6.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.6.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="row third">
    <div class="wrapper clickable">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.3.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.3.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.3.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.3.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.2.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.2.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.2.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.2.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable right-side">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.4.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.4.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.4.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.4.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row fourth">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.5.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.5.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.5.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.5.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable right-side">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.1.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.1.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.1.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.1.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="row fifth">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="wrapper join">
        <a href="">
            <span>+ Join</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper clickable right-side">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <div>
                <h2>{{team.7.name}}</h2>
                <h5>{{team.7.position}}</h5>
                <p>{{team.7.description}}</p>
                <a href="">Learn more about {{team.7.firstName}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row sixth">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="wrapper blank"></div>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="row seventh">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Full working version is avaliable here: http://jsfiddle.net/xs4mm5jd/

As you can see it works fine and animations is fast and smooth.

However, when I added some images: http://jsfiddle.net/xs4mm5jd/1/ animation is glichy. Is there any solution to speed up the performance?

Comment: Hmmm.  They both run wonderfully on chrome for mac.

Comment: Yeah it depends propably on computer speed. But after checking in Chrome inspector it rerenders all the content in each frame.

Comment: I have added version with heavier images so you can see the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/xs4mm5jd/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though I don't see bad performance in your fiddle, you can trigger hardware acceleration when animating.

Some people use a sort of hack applying either `transform: translateZ(0);` or `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to the animated elements.

Here you have a fiddle to test if you see any performance gain: http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/xs4mm5jd/3/

Here's an [article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) about it.

A second, newer (and probably better) alternative is to use the `will-change` property in your CSS, for example: `will-change: transform;`

Read more about it [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/).

Comment: I have tried before with "will-change" property but it didn`t achive any results. But this translateZ worked perfectly. Thank you a lot.